# Позитивна відповідь на негативне питання

Tags: одним-словом

Чи існує в українській мові коротка усталена ствердна відповідь на негативне питання? Щось на зразок німецького doch:

```
Ти не був у Бердичеві? - Doch!
```

Звісно, можна сказати `був, знаю, бачив`, ітн. Проте, цікаво чи є універсальна відповідь? Може це `авжеж`?

Comment: Мені здається, що проблемою «авжеж» (як і його синонімів різного ступеню близькості: «атож», «аякже», «безперечно», «безсумнівно», «безумовно», «бігма», «бігме», «годі й казати», «звичайно», «звісно», «нема сумніву», «отож», «певна річ», «певно», «ясна річ» тощо) є те, що воно може позначати як «авжеж, був», так і «авжеж, не був» — в залежності від контексту і інтонації запитання.

Answer (score 7):

Мені здається, проблемою є самі запитання із запереченням. В українській мові нейтральне «Ти не був у Бердичеві?» може припускати дві різні інтонації:

1. Коли запитувач припускає, що співрозмовник це **робив**-таки (робить, таки зробить) або навіть явно спонукає його до цього:

   > Ти не принесеш мені кави?
   >   Часом не їздив вчора до Бердичева?
2. Коли запичувач припускає, що співрозмовник цього **не робив** (не робить, не зробить), і хоче остаточно переконатися в цьому (або принаймні інтонаціями імітує таке припущення):

   > [Бачачи незорієнтованість у місті:] Так ти ще ніколи не був у Бердичеві?
   >   [Ввечері за 5 хв. до закриття магазину:] То ти вже не встигнеш купити мені каву?
   >
   > <sub>Варіації:</sub>
   >   <sub>[Здивовано:] Еге, ти що, ніколи не був у Бердичеві?!</sub>
   >   <sub>[Злісно:] Ти навіть хворій дружині кави не принесеш, покидьок?!</sub>

Так от у першому випадку відовіді на зразок «авжеж», «атож», «аякже», «безперечно», «безсумнівно», «безумовно», «бігма», «бігме», «годі й казати», «звичайно», «звісно», «нема сумніву», «певна річ», «певно», «ясна річ» без пояснень найімовірніше означатимуть, що людина це робила/робить/зробить; а другому — що не робила / не робить / не зробить.

А от відповіді «навпаки», «назворот» у другому випадку, навпаки, найімовірніше передуватимуть поясненню, чому запитувач помиляється.

Відповідно проблемою є те, що, чи має відповідач сказати «аякже!» чи «навпаки!», залежить від інтонації і контексту запитання — а якщо вони неочевидні, то обидві відповіді (без негайного продовження) можуть бути незрозумілими.

Є ще варіант відповісти здивуванням: «отакої!». Теоретично при гарному володінні інтонаціями воно в обох випадках може означати, що запитувач формально неправий («каву принесу», «в Бердичів їздив»). Але воно знов-таки передбачає продовження.